# Entity-Framework Select Distinct Name or Value shows error when returns list

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Here is the Code:

```
Public Function GetUniqueLocation() As List(Of LoginUser)
    Return db.LoginUsers.Select(Function(p) p.LocID).Distinct().ToList()
End Function
```

Here is Code error!

```
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer?)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of LoginUser)
```

Comment: I doubt you're using three different versions of EF. Please only tag the exact version you're using next time.

Comment: It's version 4........ I just asked question @ multiple forums

Comment: I've re-added the v4 tag. That's now how tags work - please only use tags that are directly relevant to the question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is quite easy to ready: you're trying to return `List(Of Integer)` from method declared as `List(Of LoginUser)`. There is no way it's gonna work.

**Seems like you're trying to get one `LoginUser` for each `LocID` property value.** But instead of that, you're just returning disting set of the property values itselve.

Instead of using `Distinct`, use `GroupBy` and `First`:

```
Public Function GetUniqueLocation() As List(Of LoginUser)
    Return db.LoginUsersGroupBy(Function(p) p.LocID).Select(Function(g) g.First()).ToList()
End Function
```

Or, **if you're really trying to return just integers**, changer your method declaration to much `List(Of Integer)` as return type:

```
Public Function GetUniqueLocation() As List(Of Integer)
    Return db.LoginUsers.Select(Function(p) p.LocID).Distinct().ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: sir, I used your 2nd answer but still the Error as   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer?)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)

Comment: Thanks sir....... it's working Now :)  Actually there was Allow Null was enable in database